# Protected Page HTML send back to Client, but its not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, authentication

I want to fetch my protected page and redirect to this page after the successful login of the user.

```
        async function getFirebaseAuthToken() {
            try {
                const email = this.email.value;
                const password = this.password.value;
                const userCredential = await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
                const user = userCredential.user;

                // Get the Firebase ID token
                const idToken = await user.getIdToken(true);
                // Decode the token (this is for debugging purposes)
                // Set the token in the request headers for subsequent requests to your server
                const response = await fetch('https://localhost:8000/admin/overview', {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        'Authorization': idToken
                    },
                });


            } catch (error) {
                // Handle login error
                console.error('Login error:', error.message);
            }
        }
```

Then in my backend I have a middleware to protect this endpoint by verifying the provided token.

```
const authenticateUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { authorization } = req.headers;
  try {
    const decodedToken = await admin.auth().verifyIdToken(authorization);
    req.user = decodedToken;
    next()

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error decoding token:', error);
    res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized' });
  }
};
```

If the middleware authenticates the user correctly I want him to go to the protected endpoint

```
app.get('/admin/overview', authenticateUser,  (req, res) => {

  const file_Path = path.join(__dirname, 'public/', 'admin.html');
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');

  // res.sendFile(file_Path);

  res.sendFile(file_Path);

});
```

I am trying around with this for a while and I am not understanding why the client is not rendering the HTML code.
Everything looks pretty good the network tab in the browser shows me that the response is correct and I can event preview it.

The browser is not rendering the HTML for some reason and also the route is still /admin/login and not /admin/overview.

Which behaviour I want is in the end this in one.

```
window.location.href = "https://localhost:8000/admin/overview";
                        // Use history.pushState to change the URL without triggering a full page reload
                const response = await fetch('https://localhost:8000/admin/overview', {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization': idToken
                },
            });
```

[image: Developer Tools]

Comment: To follow the Authorization header spec, you should be prefixing the `Authorization` header value with `"Bearer "` before the ID token. Consider using the [`verifyFirebaseIdToken()`](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/main/Node-1st-gen/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js#L26-L71) as-is to support both header-based and cookie-based authentication.

Comment: If you use the middleware linked above, this would allow you to set a `__session` cookie (this is read, but not set by the linked middleware) in the API response to authenticate all further requests.

Comment: thank you, I used it with bearer before, but I had problems with the tokens verification on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to get the correct behaviour without using the auth middleware / have you verified your middleware is correctly working? If you're still at /login that could mean your middleware isn't authenticating the user. Also, are there any errors?

The main issue seems to be that the fetch API call retrieves the HTML content, but it doesn't automatically render it in the browser. fetch is used for making HTTP requests (like GET, POST, etc.) and handling the response programmatically. It doesn't perform page redirections or render HTML content on its own. After successful login, instead of using fetch to get the HTML content, you should directly redirect the browser to the protected page. This can be done using window.location.href.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes without the middleware it works perfectly.

I thought the same but the problem then is that I can not send the userId token to authenticate the user.

Comment: If you do not have an answer this should be a comment.